# Google map w/ circle that changes every second?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a google map with a circle whose center changes every 
second? I tried the below: (also at 
http://test.barrycarter.info/sunstuff2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<style type="text/css"> 
  html { height: 100% } 
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } 
  #map_canvas { height: 100% } 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function updateJ () { 
 j = j+0.5; 
 x.center = new google.maps.LatLng(j,0); 
} 

function initialize() { 
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0); 
  var myOptions = {zoom:2,  
    center: myLatLng, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
  }; 

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
      myOptions); 

j = 20.18 

x = new google.maps.Circle({ 
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(j,-18.5037550725315), 
 radius: 10018760, 
 map: map, 
 strokeWeight: 2, 
 fillOpacity: 0.2, 
 fillColor: "#ffffff" 
}); 

} 

</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize(); updateJ(); setInterval('updateJ()', 1000)"> 
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Firebug confirms that 'j' increases every second, but this line:

```
x.center = new google.maps.LatLng(j,0);
```

does nothing. Is there a google.maps.PleaseRedrawThisObjectBecauseIHaveChangedStuff method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API functions generally don't support manually setting properties. Try using the getter/setter functions like so:

```
x.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(j, 0));
```